# Initiating Datatable Filter when using Javascript to add Text to Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables http://www.datatables.net/ for a table in my project.

I want to use the Datatables filter to filter out items from the table based on pre-defined keywords contained within my table.

The user can type in the filter which is great, but I want to give them "Shortcut" buttons with the text.

I have a working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/VjQ5L/4/

You can see when going through my buttons All - Firefox - Netscape - OSX etc I have JS working so it updates the value of the Filter Input Field.

Only problem is it does not filter, I need to press space on the keyboard when I focus on the input field for it to actually work.

I am sure there might be a quick solution like adding a filter call after each button is pressed or a blur event or something. I am just not sure how to do it..

http://jsfiddle.net/VjQ5L/4/

My JS Code

```
$(function() {

/* Table initialisation */
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'span8'l><'span8'f>r>t<'row'<'span8'i><'span8'p>>",
        "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
});

/* Adding Filter to Filter Input Field */
/* This code may not be the prettiest but best I can come up with */

            $('a.cmsFilter').click(function(){
                if($(this).text() =="All"){
                     $('#example_filter input').val('All')
                }
                else if($(this).text() =="Firefox"){
                     $('#example_filter input').val('Firefox')
                }
                else if($(this).text() =="Netscape"){
                     $('#example_filter input').val('Netscape')
                }
                else if($(this).text() =="OSX"){
                     $('#example_filter input').val('OSX')
                }
                else if($(this).text() =="Win"){
                     $('#example_filter input').val('Win')
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually able to answer this one myself, thanks from a tip from one of the admins at Datatables...

Updated Fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/VjQ5L/5/

Updated JS Pasting Below.

```
$(function () {

/* Table initialisation */

var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'span8'l><'span8'f>r>t<'row'<'span8'i><'span8'p>>",
        "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
});

/* Adding Filter to Filter Input Field */

$('a.cmsFilter').click(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "All") {
        oTable.fnFilter('');
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Firefox") {
        oTable.fnFilter('Firefox');
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Netscape") {
        oTable.fnFilter('Netscape');
    } else if ($(this).text() == "OSX") {
        oTable.fnFilter('OSX');
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Win") {
        oTable.fnFilter('Win');
    }
});
});
```